# can not get content of document with google drive sdk

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I can upload files to Google Drive using the Google Drive SDK but can't get the download to work. I have a document on google drive that I want to download and read the text in its content. I can get the file with this code:

```
    file = drive.files().get(fileId).execute();
```

The downloadUrl is always null. I don't know where I read it but someone said that Google documents does not have a downloadUrl and you should use the export links instead.

```
    String downloadUrl = driveFile.getExportLinks().get("text/plain");
    if (downloadUrl != null && downloadUrl.length() > 0) {
        try {
            HttpResponse resp = 
                    drive.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(downloadUrl)).execute();
            content = new Scanner(resp.getContent()).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        } catch (java.util.NoSuchElementException e) {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

After running this code I do not get the content in my text file but an html representation of something looking like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to Google Docs</title>
<style type="text/css">
  html, body, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, img, dl,
  dt, dd, ol, ul, li, table, tr, td, form, object, embed,
  article, aside, canvas, command, details, fieldset,
  ....
```

Can someone please explain how to read the content of a document from google drive?

**Edit**

So I can not figure out how to get the download to work with the Google Drive SDK. I did however get it to work with this code instead:

```
String downloadUrl = driveFile.getExportLinks().get("text/plain");
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(downloadUrl);
get.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
content = new java.util.Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
```

To bad when I get everything else I need to do to work with the Drive SDK. If anybody can figure out why this is working but not the code I use with the SDK please tell.

Comment: Are you sure there's no content after the html <head> ? It looks like you uploaded a file asking Google Drive to convert it. If you open the downloaded file in a browser, do you see the ocntent you expect ?

Comment: @Jerome if I open the downloaded file in a browser it does not show the content. Instead the actual text file I want to read is downloaded

Comment: @OP Try to be sure your upload is going well : do it programatically like you are already doing it, and then download the doc using Google Drive Web UI

Comment: @Jerome My uplaod is going well. When I do my upload the document show on Google Drive and when I download it as text file I can open it and my content is there.

Comment: @Jerome can it be that I loose my authentication when doing buildGetRequest or something? If I rebuild my Drive with some random access token I get the same result. And as I said, If I save the downloaded content into a html file and open it i will en up on Google login before I can download the file

Comment: Normally, as you are building your request using the authenticated Drive instance, your authentication should not be lost. What are the scopes you are using ?

Comment: You can try using API explorer to see if your protocol is working

Comment: @Jerome I am using "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"

Comment: @Jerome I'm sorry but I don't understand what you want me to do with the API explorer

Comment: Just try to download your file via the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#)

Comment: @Jerome Again I do not know what you mean. I can't find a way do do a download of a file with the Drive API explorer. When I do a drive.files.get to download file metadata it works fine. Thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

Try 'text/html'. You're exporting a rich text document, so html makes more sense than plain.

Comment: that does not help. I get the same result if I use the export link for "text/html". The String "content" does not contain the text content from the downloaded document